# EntityEntry.Property() throws InvalidOperationException when property does exist

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core

Hello all I have the following classes:

```
public class EntityA
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }

    public EntityB EntityB { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid EntityAId { get; set; }
    public EntityA EntityA { get; set; }
}
```

And I have the following runtime code:

```
var a1 = new EntityA {Desc = "a1"};
var a2 = new EntityA {Desc = "a2"};
dbx.EntityAs.Add(a1);
dbx.EntityAs.Add(a2);

var b1 = new EntityB { EntityAId = a1.Id };
dbx.EntityBs.Add(b1);
dbx.SaveChanges();
b1.EntityAId = a2.Id;
dbx.SaveChanges();
```

I have modified codes in my DbContext.SaveChanges() method as below, trying to find which property in an entity has changed and its before and after values:

```
foreach (var entity in changedEntites)
{
var entityType = entity.Entity.GetType();

if (entity.State == EntityState.Modified)
{                  
    var properties = entityType.GetProperties();
    var props = new List<object>();
    foreach (var prop in properties)
    {
        if(entityType.GetProperty(prop.Name) == null)
            continue;
        var pp = entityType.GetProperty(prop.Name);
        if(pp.GetValue(entity.Entity) == null)
            continue;

        var p = entity.Property(prop.Name);
        if (p.IsModified)
            props.Add(new { f = prop.Name, o = p.OriginalValue, c = p.CurrentValue });
    }
}
}
```

The problematic code is at this line:

```
var p = entity.Property(prop.Name);
```

It throws `InvalidOperationException`:

```
The property 'EntityA' on entity type 'EntityB' could not be found.
Ensure that the property exists and has been included in the model.
```

My question is why even `entityType.GetProperty(prop.Name)` and `entityType.GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(entity.Entity)` is not null, `entity.Property()` still not able to find the property?

I can just surround `var p = entity.Property(prop.Name);` with a try-catch block and ignore the exception, but letting exceptions to keep throwing in an auditing scenario is not a good thing. It also does performance impact.

Any workaround is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that `Property` method supports only primitive properties while you are calling it with navigation property.

You can use ER Core metadata services accessible via `EntityEntry.Metadata` property which returns `IEntityType`. In your case, the `FindProperty` method, although you should really use `GetProperties` instead of reflection at the first place:

```
if (entity.Metadata.FindProperty(prop.Name) == null)
    continue;

var p = entity.Property(prop.Name);
if (p.IsModified)
    props.Add(new { f = prop.Name, o = p.OriginalValue, c = p.CurrentValue });
```

Comment: Thank you. That's what I need. Searched though Google and EF doc site its so frustrating that the documentation didn't mention about Property method supports only primitive properties.

Answer (score 0):

This because `entity` is `EntityEntry`. You should correctly name your variable to not get confused:

```
foreach (var entiry in changedEntries)
{
    var entity = entiry.Entity;
    var entityType = entity.GetType();

    if (entity.State == EntityState.Modified)
    {                  
        var properties = entityType.GetProperties();
        var props = new List<object>();
        foreach (var prop in properties)
        {
            if(entityType.GetProperty(prop.Name) == null)
                continue;
            var pp = entityType.GetProperty(prop.Name);
            if(pp.GetValue(entity) == null)
                continue;

            var p = entity.Property(prop.Name);
            if (p.IsModified)
                props.Add(new { f = prop.Name, o = p.OriginalValue, c = p.CurrentValue });
        }
    }
}
```